# Makefile of Lex and Yacc

Tags: c, makefile, yacc, lex

right now, I am facing with the problem where my makefile is error. Assume I have 4 files: project.l **(Lex file)**, project.y **(Yacc file)**, **main.c** (my main source file where I called the parser) and the **makefile** below:

```
main: y.tab.o lex.yy.o 
    gcc -o main main.c y.tab.o lex.yy.o -ly -ll

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c

y.tab.c y.tab.h: project.y
    yacc -d project.y

y.tab.o: y.tab.c 
    gcc -c y.tab.c

lex.yy.o: y.tab.h lex.yy.c 
    gcc -c lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c: project.l 
    lex project.l
```

I got an error said as following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_parse", referenced from:
      _main in main-5771ff.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I thought it isn't a problem on my code because when I ran:

```
lex project.l
yacc -d project.y
gcc -o main main.c lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll -ly
```

Respectively, and there isn't any problem. What should I do?

Comment: Did you really mean to list main.c instead of main.o when doing your linking?

Comment: Didn't you mean to call `yyparse` on your main file instead of `parse`?

Comment: In the 1st line, `main:` does not list `main.o` on right side, and (as LogicG8 already mentioned) the 2nd line does compile `main.c` instead of link `main.o`. The 2nd issue may probably work but in this case the 2nd rule is unnecessary and `main.c` should be on right side of 1st line.